# Build number with addition and multiplication

Tags: arrays, math, logic, computer-science

I am participating in a contest and can't seem to find a good solution to this problem:

We're given a number called Target, and a sequence of natural numbers, length of the sequence unspecified.

Find out the closest we can come to Target only by using addition and multiplication between the numbers given, without using brackets '()' and each number not more than once.

examples:

```
$ cat test_case_1.txt
3972
87 5 47
$
$ ./program < test_case_1.txt
4089
87*47
$
$ cat test_case_2.txt
119
3 5 17 37 61 87
$
$ ./program < test_case_2.txt
119
87+17+5*3
$
$ cat test_case_3.txt
424
17 19 23 29 31
$
$ ./program < test_case_3.txt
422
31+23*17
$
$ cat test_case_4.txt
1337
23 29 31 47 53
$
$ ./program < test_case_4.txt
1326
47+31+29+23*53
$
$ cat test_case_5.txt
4291
31 47 53 67 71 79 83
$
$ ./program < test_case_5.txt
4289
71+31+53*79
$
$ cat test_case_6.txt
256952
5 7 11 17 47 67 71
$
$ ./program < test_case_6.txt
256954
5+7*11*47*71
$
```

Comment: This seems to be an NP-hard problem. Can you double check whether there are any more constraints to the problem than the ones that you have specified?

Comment: not really, it only mentions that the numbers are distinct. I'm waiting for an answer if the numbers given are prime or not. In the example they seem to be, except for 87.

Comment: The case where only addition allowed and an exact match is possible is exactly the same as subset sum, which is known to be NP-Complete. It seems like allowing multiplication would probably make it harder, not easier to solve. I suspect there is a `O(2^N)` algorithm using dynamic programming. Also, the numbers being prime is rather unlikely to help. How long are the sequences? How much time/space are you allowed? Is a desired time/space complexity listed?

Comment: If the problem you are trying to solve is the same as Google Translate tells me of [this github found via copying a section of the examples and using Google](https://github.com/dserban/lambda2014summer/issues/2), then it looks like O(2^N) is probably the best you can hope for and as noted in the comments, memoization (along with Dynamic programming) seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for the support, you were right with the Dynamic programming solution.